# Qt5 (5.7) Websockets do not work on Windows Phone

Tags: c++, qt, windows-phone-8.1, qt5

Hello dear fellow programmers,
we try to write an application that will run on windows phone and android.
Part of this app ist to establish a secure connection to a websocket server, which does not work on the windows phone. Works however perfect under Linux.

```
//constructor opening connection
 MeteorDDP::MeteorDDP(QString uri){
   QUrl wsUri = QUrl("wss://"+uri+"/websocket");
   qDebug()<<wsUri;
      connect(&wsClient, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,this, &MeteorDDP::handleMessage);


 connect(&wsClient, &QWebSocket::connected,this, &MeteorDDP::onConnected);
   connect(&wsClient, &QWebSocket::stateChanged, this, &MeteorDDP::onStateChanged);
   connect(&wsClient, static_cast<void(QWebSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QWebSocket::error),
       [=](QAbstractSocket::SocketError error){
        qDebug()<<error<<"error";
   });
   connect(&wsClient, &QWebSocket::sslErrors, this, &MeteorDDP::onSslError);
       wsClient.open(wsUri);
       wsClient.flush();
    }
```

And a method which just should output connected:

```
void MeteorDDP::onConnected(){
    qDebug()<<"connected";
}
```

H file:

```
#ifndef METEORDDP_H
#define METEORDDP_H
#include <QString>
#include <QHash>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtWebSockets/QtWebSockets>

class MeteorDDP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MeteorDDP(QString server);
protected: 
 QWebSocket wsClient;
 void onConnected();
void onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state);
void onSslError(void);
void onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error);
}
```

Methods:

```
void MeteorDDP::onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state){
    qDebug() <<state<<"state Changed";
}
void MeteorDDP::onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error){
     qDebug()<<error <<"error";
}
void MeteorDDP::onSslError(){
     qDebug() <<"ssl error";
}
```

Comment: If your `onConnected` method isn't being called the first thing to do would be to connect to a few other signals such as [`error`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#error-1) and [`stateChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#stateChanged) to see what extra information you can get regarding the connection process.

Comment: I got exactly one singal, that the state changed to connecting and then nothing.

Comment: And it works with not using ssl (ws instead of wss)